# Summing all values with same ID in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, attribute-table, summarizing

I did a one to many spatial join and ended up with an attribute table as follows:
Lets say we have 5 different IDs that have numerical values in 500 rows. I need to sum the values for each ID, and end up with 5 rows of data containing the ID and the total of all values that had that ID. Is group by the right tool for this? If so, how exactly do I use it?

Please note that these numbers are simplified and the actual number of rows is much larger.

Comment: can I do that in the spatial join one to one (instead of one to many) and sum that field in specific for all intersections with the same ID?

Comment: This question is essentially a duplicate of any number of questions dealing with grouping/summarizing data: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/95803/avg-and-group-by-in-arcmap, http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/102507/summarizing-data-on-arcgis-10-1

Comment: okay so the answer to them is using summary statistics.... I knew the tool existed. I just don't know how to utilize it in my case, which is clearly different from both cases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [Dissolve tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000005n000000).

You choose the dissolve field (ID) and then SUM for the statistics.

Comment: thanks for sharing, from the looks of it the dissolve tool can be helpful when dealing with huge tables (hundreds of thousands of rows).

Answer (score 7):

If you are only interested in the attribute table, you can use the [Summary Statistics](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00080000001z000000) tool, where 'Statistics Fields' = fields to sum, 'Statistics Type' = SUM, and 'Case Field' = ID.

Comment: I guess I could join that to the original shapefile

Answer (score 2):

Right click the field and choose "Summarize" then choose your field and the method by which to summarize that field. Sum is what you are looking for.