# Writing python script to group and sum records from each group?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, field-calculator, python-parser

I am doing hydrology analysis in ArcMap 10.2 and have a drainage area feature class containing hundreds of records.  Each record is assigned a drainage area name and acreage amount.

How do I sum all the acreage amounts for each drainage area name using a python script preferably in the field calculator?

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/118628/how-to-sum-all-values-with-the-same-id-in-arcgis-desktop may provide some ideas.

Comment: arcpy.Dissolve_management(feature_class,outputname,[drainage_field or fields],['Acres','SUM'])

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].  For questions that involve code we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) (or in this case an expression and code block) in your question.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **`{}`** button that enables you to format any highlighted code nicely.

Answer (score 3):

If you do not necessarily need to use python to do this, you can use the Summary Statistics (Analysis) tool.

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00080000001z000000

Select your acreage field as the Statistics Field(s) with a Statistic Type of SUM, and select your drainage area name field as the Case Field.

Comment: I agree - the Field Calculator is the wrong tool for trying to do this, irrespective of whether [it can be done](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/225042/115) using it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this, somewhat cumbersomely, in the field calculator like:

Parser: Python

Expression:

```
my_func(!YOUR_GROUP_FIELD!)
```

Codeblock:

```
def my_func(group):
  fc = 'YOUR_FEATURE_LAYER'
  sum_field = 'YOUR_SUM_FIELD'
  group_field = 'YOUR_GROUP_FIELD'
  wc = "{0} = {1}".format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(fc,group_field),group)
  return sum([i[0] for i in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc,sum_field,wc)])
```