# Sum polygon areas by class in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, field-calculator

I've been looking for a way to sum the total areas of each polygon in specific classes using ModelBuilder. Many have suggested the "Summarise Statistics" option which creates a new table, is there any way of doing this by "Calculate Field" in a Total_ha field I've created especially in the original table for this? I have several hundred shape files to do, it would be a pain to have to join them with the Summary table...

Comment: I would use Summary Statistics but [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/225042/115) to the duplicate looks like it should do what you want.

Answer (score -1):

There is a function comparable to Field Calculator, 'Calculate Geometry' that I think will work here.

To use it in ArcMap you open the attribute table of your layer, then right click the title of your target column, Total_ha in your case and choose Calculate Geometry.

This opens a dialogue where you can choose which stats you want to calculate, such as area or perimeter, you can also choose a unit of measurement.

I don't know exactly how to use this function in Model Builder but for the arcpy implementation you use arcpy.CalculateField_management() and use the shape token. 
Python example: 
(Total_ha =)
!shape.area@SQUAREMETERS!

See: http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/calculate-field.htm

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.